# Haskell 2 Decimal points

Tags: haskell, decimal

Im trying to find out a way to limit Haskell in order to return numbers with just 2 decimal namers (ex. 1.24)

My code is :

```
sumSquares = sum . map (^ 2)
```

How is possible to do that in Haskell
Thank you!

Comment: You need to do it where you convert to string not in the calculation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
import Text.Printf (printf)

 . . .
printf "%.2g" pi
```

You should get 3.14

Comment: I tried with printf but I can't get it right. Im getting errors
It gonna be something like this: sumSquares = printf "%.2g" (sum . map (^ 2))

Comment: @user3207652 it should be `printf "%.2g" . sum . map (^2)`

Answer (score 1):

I found it easier to create a function that does it than understanding the issues of printf

```
toNDecimals decimals number = let
    toFloat n  = read n :: Float
    totalChars = (+) (decimals+1) $ getPos '.' (show number) 0
        where getPos c (x:xs) n
                  | x == c    = n
                  | otherwise = getPos c (xs) n+1
    in toFloat $ take totalChars $ show number
```

So

```
toNDecimals 2 141.39682312
```

Returns
*141.39*